# Convert mysql String into Paragraphs, links, quotes, etc

Tags: php

I'm developing a Blog, and I want to give some Style to the content of Every post body.
I'm storaging each post with a form into my data base, and then retrieving it into the blog.
My form has Title, Date and Body.
What I need is to retrieve the body, and separate the paragraphs, quotes, and whatever I want to.
My idea was to add characters in the body like % or & (% mean paragraph, and & quote for example), so the I can use explote function.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd honestly be so much better to store your post's content as HTML and simply output that.

You'll have to implement security yourself but this could be as simple as using the `strip_tags()` function - example:

```
$post_body = strip_tags($_POST['body'], '<p><strong><em><span><a><blockquote>');
```

This would simply strip all HTML tags other than `<p>`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<span>`, `<a>` and `<blockquote>`. That should prevent any issues with malicious users inserting Javascript code etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll try that way! Thank you @Connor Gurney

Comment: Good luck @GastónVidal, hope it works for you! All the best.